# Chilkat: Signing an email with certificate from Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider (CNG)

Tags: chilkat

We are using Chilkat for sending emails and we need to sign emails
   also with CNG certificates (using `Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider`).

It looks like Chilkat cannot SetSigningCert(), because the Chilkat.
   Cert opened from CertStore does not include the private key. Only
   SetSigningCert2 (,privateKey) works for me, when that cert was
   exportable and when I exported that private key on my own way and
   imported it with Chilkat as PrivateKey.Load. We should also have a
   solution for none-exportable CNG certificates to sign a Chilkat
   email.

Answer (score 0):

If using an older version of Chilkat, update to the latest version (v9.50.79 at the time of this message post) and try again...